# blender export fbx lose the origin rest pose

Tags: export, .fbx

I download a `.fbx` from mixamo, import it with blender. However, when export to a new fbx from blender, the rest pose is been changed. If export to `.bvh` or  `.glb`, the rest pose is same as origin file. I tried both in GUI and with `python script`, the conclusion is the same. I wonder why it is? Look forward to your help.

> this is the origin rest pose

[image: origin rest pose]

> this is the rest pose after exporting (become a frame of the animation)

[image: after exporting to fbx]

> below is my python script

```py
armature_name = "Armature"

bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=file, axis_forward="-Z", axis_up="Y")


# print(bpy.data.objects["Geometry"])
# print(bpy.data.armatures["Geometry"])

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects[armature_name].select_set(True)
# 为了选中mesh
if len(bpy.data.objects[armature_name].children) > 0:
    bpy.data.objects[armature_name].children[0].select_set(True)


bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="m01_test.fbx",
                         use_selection=True, add_leaf_bones=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a very old bug with Blender FBX exporter that never got fixed, it doesn't export armature binding / rest pose with the animation, only animation tracks are exported with armature.

To fix this you can add a dummy mesh bound to the armature deform, and export the skeletal mesh as well. When exporting skeletal meshes the exporter will export both the rest pose of the mesh and the rest pose of the armature.

Then import both of the mesh and the animation into any game engine, and export the armature with animation from game engine for asset house keeping.

Any game engine can export animations correctly with the armature and its binding / rest pose.

---

Even though Blender FBX exporter has such bug and other limitations, it's still the best FBX exporter for exporting Blender animations. Other exporters are not as reliable for example they couldn't change the primary bone axis that point to its child bone, or couldn't extract animation tracks from animation layers plugin and says it's read only, or couldn't bake animations correctly from complex rigs, etc. The default FBX exporter is still the most reliable for exporting Blender animations. Other format support like USD export needs lots of improvements to be usable and compatible with other programmes.